# Visualforce page functionality not preserved through change set

Tags: apex, visualforce, change-set, pageblocktable, production

After a couple of weeks of developing and testing a visualforce page, we decided it was time to go live (rather, it was time for everything to start going wrong..). After pushing the custom objects, fields, buttons, controllers, and pages through to production using a change set, the functionality was hindered in two of the three tables. They are developed the exact same, using apex:pageBlockTable and apex:column with a nested inputfield or outputfield, depending on the field. Anyway, the one table works exactly as it did in the sandbox. The other 2, do not. After looking into the source code, the table that still works has tags nested under td, such as select or span. The two that are not working just have the td tags, and that's it. Also of note, I have add/delete row functionality working on all three of them. If I query for the objects (rows) that I add on the broken tables, it is showing that they are saved. Another thing I just noticed is that if I add the fields to the query that are not showing on the visualforce page, the editor tells me there is no such column on that entity. However, if I look at the object in setup I can see that field exists. Yes it is spelled right and yes I'm working in the same org. Also I have verified that it was included in the change set. Does someone have an idea of what's going on here? I am at a lost and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Field level security maybe? Usually the first thing I check when I run into the type of issues you described

Comment: You were correct. Thanks for your time. Won't make that mistake again..